# Blazor Server Side JSInterop Not Working On IIS But Works On IIS Express

Tags: c#, iis, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have developed a small Blazor Server Side application for internal use.  The application works great when I run it on my machine using IIS Express.  However when we move it to the server and run it under IIS, the interop commands stop working.

Example:

await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("alert","Printing");

Everything else works perfectly, it's only JSInterop that stops working.  I have been Googling but can't find any reason this would stop working.  I've also tried running locally on IIS and has the same issue.  Websockets are enabled and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: No errors in both consoles, server and browser ?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing.

Comment: Please provide error details, otherwise your problem cannot be solved.